# Enable Website access from both www and non-www

Tags: python, cpanel

I recently hosted my site on Cpanel, however, I am still not able to find the right solution for my problem.
I intend to make my site accessible from  `www.site.com` too.
Currently accessing the site using the above returns the following on the browser

> ```
> This site can’t be reached
> www.site.com’s server IP address could not be found.
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
> ```

How can I make the site accessible using `www.site.com` as well? Probably using `.htaccess` file

Adding the following on my .htaccess file still does not work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It's a Python app

Comment: What happens when you try to access the site from a different browser? And have a look [here](https://tribulant.com/docs/hosting-domains/hosting/9867/redirecting-to-www-or-non-www/)

Comment: No difference still

Comment: Did you contact the hosting service provider about the problem?

Comment: Not yet, i though of giving it a try first to see if i could find a way through

Comment: My advice is first see what they will tell you and then try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you are getting the error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". This means that the DNS record for [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) is missing. You need to add a CNAME or A record for [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) to point to the IP address of your server.

You can add the records from cPanel >> Zone editor.
https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/zone-editor/

This works only if your nameservers are the same as your hosting server. If you are using any other nameserver you will need to add the records on it.